# How can I calculate FLOPs and Params without 0 weights neurons affected?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pruning, flops

My Prune code is shown below, after running this, I will get a file named 'pruned_model.pth'.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.utils.prune as prune
import torch.nn.functional as F
from cnn import net

ori_model = '/content/drive/My Drive/ECG_weight_prune/checkpoint_dir/model.pth'
save_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/ECG_weight_prune/checkpoint_dir/pruned_model.pth'
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = net().to(device)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(ori_model))  

module = model.conv1
print(list(module.named_parameters()))
print(list(module.named_buffers()))

prune.l1_unstructured(module, name="weight", amount=0.3)
prune.l1_unstructured(module, name="bias", amount=3)
print(list(module.named_parameters()))
print(list(module.named_buffers()))
print(module.bias)
print(module.weight)
print(module._forward_pre_hooks)
prune.remove(module, 'weight')
prune.remove(module, 'bias')
print(list(module.named_parameters()))
print(model.state_dict())
torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)
```

and results is :

```
[('weight', Parameter containing:
tensor([[[-0.0000, -0.3137, -0.3221,  ...,  0.5055,  0.3614, -0.0000]],

        [[ 0.8889,  0.2697, -0.3400,  ...,  0.8546,  0.2311, -0.0000]],

        [[-0.2649, -0.1566, -0.0000,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.3855]],

        ...,

        [[-0.2836, -0.0000,  0.2155,  ..., -0.8894, -0.7676, -0.6271]],

        [[-0.7908, -0.6732, -0.5024,  ...,  0.2011,  0.4627,  1.0227]],

        [[ 0.4433,  0.5048,  0.7685,  ..., -1.0530, -0.8908, -0.4799]]],
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)), ('bias', Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.7497, -1.3594, -1.7613, -2.0137, -1.1763,  0.4150, -1.6996, -1.5354,
         0.4330, -0.9259,  0.4156, -2.3099, -0.4282, -0.5199,  0.1188, -1.1725,
        -0.9064, -1.6639, -1.5834, -0.3655, -2.0727, -2.1078, -1.6431, -0.0694,
        -0.5435, -1.9623,  0.5481, -0.8255, -1.5108, -0.4029, -1.9759,  0.0522,
         0.0599, -2.2469, -0.5599,  0.1039, -0.4472, -1.1706, -0.0398, -1.9441,
        -1.5310, -0.0837, -1.3250, -0.2098, -0.1919,  0.4600, -0.8268, -1.0041,
        -0.8168, -0.8701,  0.3869,  0.1706, -0.0226, -1.2711, -0.9302, -2.0696,
        -1.1838,  0.4497, -1.1426,  0.0772, -2.4356, -0.3138,  0.6297,  0.2022,
        -0.4024,  0.0000, -1.2337,  0.2840,  0.4515,  0.2999,  0.0273,  0.0374,
         0.1325, -0.4890, -2.3845, -1.9663,  0.2108, -0.1144,  0.0544, -0.2629,
         0.0393, -0.6728, -0.9645,  0.3118, -0.5142, -0.4097, -0.0000, -1.5142,
        -1.2798,  0.2871, -2.0122, -0.9346, -0.4931, -1.4895, -1.1401, -0.8823,
         0.2210,  0.4282,  0.1685, -1.8876, -0.7459,  0.2505, -0.6315,  0.3827,
        -0.3348,  0.1862,  0.0806, -2.0277,  0.2068,  0.3281, -1.8045, -0.0000,
        -2.2377, -1.9742, -0.5164, -0.0660,  0.8392,  0.5863, -0.7301,  0.0778,
         0.1611,  0.0260,  0.3183, -0.9097, -1.6152,  0.4712, -0.2378, -0.4972],
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True))]
```

There are many zero weights existing. How can I calculate FLOPs and Params without counting calculations associated with these zero values?

I use the following code to calculate FLOPs and Params.

```
import torch
from cnn import net
from ptflops import get_model_complexity_info

ori_model = '/content/drive/My Drive/ECG_weight_prune/checkpoint_dir/model.pth'
pthfile = '/content/drive/My Drive/ECG_weight_prune/checkpoint_dir/pruned_model.pth'

model = net()
# model.load_state_dict(torch.load(ori_model))  
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(pthfile))  
# print(model.state_dict())

macs, params = get_model_complexity_info(model, (1, 260), as_strings=False,
                                         print_per_layer_stat=True, verbose=True)
print('{:<30}  {:<8}'.format('Computational complexity: ', macs))
print('{:<30}  {:<8}'.format('Number of parameters: ', params))
```

The output of both ori_model nad pthfile is the same, as follows.

```
Warning: module Dropout2d is treated as a zero-op.
Warning: module Flatten is treated as a zero-op.
Warning: module net is treated as a zero-op.
net(
  0.05 M, 100.000% Params, 0.001 GMac, 100.000% MACs, 
  (conv1): Conv1d(0.007 M, 13.143% Params, 0.0 GMac, 45.733% MACs, 1, 128, kernel_size=(50,), stride=(3,))
  (conv2): Conv1d(0.029 M, 57.791% Params, 0.001 GMac, 50.980% MACs, 128, 32, kernel_size=(7,), stride=(1,))
  (conv3): Conv1d(0.009 M, 18.619% Params, 0.0 GMac, 0.913% MACs, 32, 32, kernel_size=(9,), stride=(1,))
  (fc1): Linear(0.004 M, 8.504% Params, 0.0 GMac, 0.404% MACs, in_features=32, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(0.001 M, 1.299% Params, 0.0 GMac, 0.063% MACs, in_features=128, out_features=5, bias=True)
  (bn1): BatchNorm1d(0.0 M, 0.515% Params, 0.0 GMac, 1.793% MACs, 128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (bn2): BatchNorm1d(0.0 M, 0.129% Params, 0.0 GMac, 0.114% MACs, 32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (dropout): Dropout2d(0.0 M, 0.000% Params, 0.0 GMac, 0.000% MACs, p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (faltten): Flatten(0.0 M, 0.000% Params, 0.0 GMac, 0.000% MACs, )
)
Computational complexity:       1013472.0
Number of parameters:           49669
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to estimate computational complexity IF the operations were not carried out?

Comment: Yes, because after pruing, there will be many 0s which should not be count into the number of FLOPs and params. In this way, I can see the improvement of pruning.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to exclude the weights below a certain threshold from the FLOPs computation. To do so you would have to modify the flop counter functions.

I'll provide examples for the modification for fc and conv layers below.

```
def linear_flops_counter_hook(module, input, output):
    input = input[0]
    output_last_dim = output.shape[-1]  # pytorch checks dimensions, so here we don't care much
    # MODIFICATION HAPPENS HERE
    num_zero_weights = (module.weight.data.abs() < 1e-9).sum()
    zero_weights_factor = 1 - torch.true_divide(num_zero_weights, module.weight.data.numel())
    module.__flops__ += int(np.prod(input.shape) * output_last_dim) * zero_weights_factor.numpy()
    # MODIFICATION HAPPENS HERE
```

```
def conv_flops_counter_hook(conv_module, input, output):
    # Can have multiple inputs, getting the first one
    input = input[0]

    batch_size = input.shape[0]
    output_dims = list(output.shape[2:])

    kernel_dims = list(conv_module.kernel_size)
    in_channels = conv_module.in_channels
    out_channels = conv_module.out_channels
    groups = conv_module.groups

    filters_per_channel = out_channels // groups
    conv_per_position_flops = int(np.prod(kernel_dims)) * in_channels * filters_per_channel

    active_elements_count = batch_size * int(np.prod(output_dims))

    # MODIFICATION HAPPENS HERE
    num_zero_weights = (conv_module.weight.data.abs() < 1e-9).sum()
    zero_weights_factor = 1 - torch.true_divide(num_zero_weights, conv_module.weight.data.numel())
    overall_conv_flops = conv_per_position_flops * active_elements_count * zero_weights_factor.numpy()
    # MODIFICATION HAPPENS HERE
    
    bias_flops = 0

    if conv_module.bias is not None:

        bias_flops = out_channels * active_elements_count

    overall_flops = overall_conv_flops + bias_flops

    conv_module.__flops__ += int(overall_flops)
```

Note that I'm using 1e-9 as a threshold for a weight counting as zero.